# Is there a windows-specific installation of awk for version 4.x?

Tags: windows, awk, gnu

I'm using gawk for Windows from GnuWin32 (https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuwin32/), version 3.1.6.  I haven't been able to find a more recent version of gawk for windows that has a "windows-specific" installation program.  (And it doesn't look like gunwin32 is very active recently.)  Is there one?  I know I can download the source and try building from that, but I'm looking for a windows-specific installation program.  Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [ezwinports](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/files/). Once this has been said, this question is off topic here. Next time, please, you can try with [Software Recomendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks for that. I didn't realize that topic was available.

Comment: I did look at ezwinports, and they did have a 4.1.4. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[MC ND](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2861476/mc-nd) commented above, and [valrog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8422345/valrog) posted in another forum: "Try with gawk 4.1.4 from ezwinports at sourceforge."

I'm trying them now. Thanks. to both.